# QT Designer не могу запустить цикл while для обновления сообщения в Label в графическом окне

Tags: python, циклы, qt-designer

Python, QT Desinger  на форму закинул PushButton при нажатии на который подключается
к счету и показывает данные об счете на Label (в теории должно быть обновление информации на Qlabel).
По факту Цикл while в коде обновляет данные только в консоли (там паралельно тоже выводит), а вот в самом графическом окне нет ... :/
Проше говоря: почему для консоли цикл работает, а для Label в GUI нет !

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: циклы `while` и `time.sleep` блокируют интерфейс. Тяжелая задача должна выполняться в отдельном потоке, из которой вы передает данные в основной поток. Сигналы и слоты используются для связи между объектами. Механизм сигналов и слотов - центральная особенность Qt и, вероятно, часть, которая больше всего отличается от функций, предоставляемых другими фреймворками.

Comment: а что с вашим предыдущим вопросом?

Comment: предыдуший вопрос завис у меня, не в силах его разобрать эту тему :/  пошел к след вопросу более важному: изучение потоков как вы и сказали это единственный выход

Answer (score 0):

с ним должно работать. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents
скорее всего у тебя в одном потоке вайл стоит, поэтому нет сообщения на обновление отрисовки

Comment: а как использовать кратко, если можно этот processEvents ? В документации не разберешся без пол литра :/       Использовал перерисовку self.repaint() .. данные обновляет, но как нажмеш на форму то программа зависает